# What security consideration are in software part and what are in Server configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I'm an Asp.net programmer.I want to know What security consideration are in software part and waht are in Server configuration to prevent hack.

for example I know that preventing SQL injection is software part but preventing deface a site is in server part.

what security risk I must be consider in coding?

Comment: This is a really broad question. Try asking something more specific. There's an entire website on preventing (or attempting to prevent) hacking: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Exactly I know this is broad ques but I want any body just give a short answer and give us his/her personal experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For beginners:

- XSS => always HTML encode anything that comes from the user
- SQL Injection => always use parametrized queries
- Mass assignment => always always use view models
- CSRF => use anti forgery tokens

... this list continues on the [Developer Highway Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/security/aa473878.aspx) (probably the most comprehensive guide ...).

As far as the server configuration part is concerned don't hesitate to ask your question on http://serverfault.com where you will get answers from people specializing in this area of expertize.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [OWASP Top 10 for 2010](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main) for a concise overview of common security vulnerabilities and steps to mitigate them. As others have said, this is a broad and complex topic, but the top 10 can point you to the concepts that you need to master.